# biblatex - How can I print out the date (always provided as YYYY-MM) as a string at the end of a block?

Tags: biblatex

At the end of an entry for `standardisodin`, I'd like to have the content in of the `Date`-field printed out like this:

> [...] Stuff, Version: May 2011.

I think the month would get changed to my language lateron, but adding the string *Version*, I haven't been successful at all yet.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
12pt,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear-ibid,
backend=biber,
hyperref=true,
dashed=false,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
sorting=nyt,
firstinits=true,
uniquename=init,
uniquelist=false,
autocite=footnote,
ibidtracker=true,
date=comp,
mincrossrefs=1,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%definition of new source type: Standard (ISO, DIN, or other guidelines)
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{standardisodin}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[standardisodin]{type,number}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{standardisodin}{%
\usebibmacro{bibindex}%
\usebibmacro{begentry}%
%\usebibmacro{author}%
%\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
\printfield{type}\addspace%
\printfield{number}\addcolon\addspace%
\usebibmacro{title}\addspace%
%\newunit\newblock
%\usebibmacro{location+date}%
\newunit\newblock
\printfield{date}
\newunit\newblock
\iftoggle{bbx:url}
{\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
{}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
\setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
\usebibmacro{pageref}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{related}%
\usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteindex
    {\indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}%
    \ifentrytype{standardisodin} 
    {\printfield{type}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printfield{number}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}}
    {}
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
        {\ifentrytype{standardisodin}
            {\printfield{type}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \printfield{number}}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
                    \setunit{\addspace}}
                {\printnames{labelname}%
                    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
                \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Standardisodin{abc,
Title                    = {Stuff},
Author                   = {{DIN Deutsches Institut für Normung e.~V.}},
Date                     = {2011-05},
Location                 = {Berlin},
Number                   = {333444},
Type                     = {DIN},
Year                     = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\citetitle{abc}
\end{flushleft}

Words.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your actual question, but `biblatex` (or rather Biber) is not too keen on your providing both `date` and `year` information: You should give only the `date` field.

Comment: @moewe I was not aware of that (as I had not read the corresponding part in the manual). Hm... I think I have to re-organize my `.bib`-file then.

Comment: As it stands now, Biber just ignores the `year` field and nothing goes horribly wrong. But your `.bib` file is unnecessarily bloated and confusing to humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the date, it's easiest to go with `\printdate`, if you are not OK with the format `\printdate` gives you, we will have to go through greater lengths to achieve a nice output.

The code we'll add is

```
\iffieldundef{year}
  {}
  {\printtext{Version:} \printdate}%
```

It will print the date and the prefix "Version" only if a date is present (note that `biblatex`/Biber automatically decompose the `date` field into its parts `year`, `month` and `date`).

In the driver

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{standardisodin}{%
\usebibmacro{bibindex}%
\usebibmacro{begentry}%
%\usebibmacro{author}%
%\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
\printfield{type}
\setunit{\addspace}%
\printfield{number}
\setunit{\addcolon\space}%
\usebibmacro{title}
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
%\usebibmacro{location+date}%
\iffieldundef{year}
  {}
  {\printtext{Version:} \printdate}%
\newunit\newblock
\iftoggle{bbx:url}
{\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
{}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
\setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
\usebibmacro{pageref}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{related}%
\usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
12pt,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear-ibid,
backend=biber,
hyperref=true,
dashed=false,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
sorting=nyt,
firstinits=true,
uniquename=init,
uniquelist=false,
autocite=footnote,
ibidtracker=true,
date=comp,
mincrossrefs=1,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%definition of new source type: Standard (ISO, DIN, or other guidelines)
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{standardisodin}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[standardisodin]{type,number}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{standardisodin}{%
\usebibmacro{bibindex}%
\usebibmacro{begentry}%
%\usebibmacro{author}%
%\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
\printfield{type}
\setunit{\addspace}%
\printfield{number}
\setunit{\addcolon\space}%
\usebibmacro{title}
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
%\usebibmacro{location+date}%
\iffieldundef{year}
  {}
  {\printtext{Version:} \printdate}%
\newunit\newblock
\iftoggle{bbx:url}
{\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
{}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
\setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
\usebibmacro{pageref}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{related}%
\usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteindex
    {\indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}%
    \ifentrytype{standardisodin} 
    {\printfield{type}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printfield{number}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}}
    {}
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
        {\ifentrytype{standardisodin}
            {\printfield{type}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \printfield{number}}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
                    \setunit{\addspace}}
                {\printnames{labelname}%
                    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
                \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Standardisodin{abc,
Title                    = {Stuff},
Author                   = {{DIN Deutsches Institut für Normung e.~V.}},
Date                     = {2011-05},
Location                 = {Berlin},
Number                   = {333444},
Type                     = {DIN},
}

@Standardisodin{def,
Title                    = {No Date},
Author                   = {{DIN Deutsches Institut für Normung e.~V.}},
Location                 = {Berlin},
Number                   = {333444},
Type                     = {DIN},
addendum = {hi},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\citetitle{abc}
\end{flushleft}

Words.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note how I used `\setunit{\addcomma\space}` instead of bare `\addcomma\addspace` in the answer above. This will prevent punctuation havoc if some field is missing.

Comment: Interesting, with every bit you learn more... ok, so as I commented earlier to your comment above, I was not aware that `year` is retain support for "old" code for Bibtex. I'll hapily switch to `date` only. Can I delete the if-check then?

Comment: Since `year` was the default field provided in JabRef (IIRC), I kept using it. So I have a database with lots of mixed entries... damnit. Hm, will post more on this to superuser.com.

Comment: @henry Actually `data` is just for our convenience, it is decomposed to `year`, `month` and `day` internally. It is perfectly fine to use only `year = {2011}` in your `.bib` file, but both `year` *and* `date` in the same entry is excessive and outright confusing (`biblatex-examples.bib` has some entries using `date` and some only `year`). - The `\iffieldundef{year}` needs to be retained in any way as this is the only way to check whether there really is a date present, otherwise we would see "Version: ." if the date (and with it certainly the year) is missing.

Comment: @henry Please note also that my advice about `\setunit` above decidedly does not apply to the `\newunit` or `\newblock` commands.

Comment: Getting help like this is a lot of fun, thank you. I was aware of this, btw.

Comment: Well since I would at least like to try to have a "clean" database all in all, I opened a thread [here](http://superuser.com/questions/808094/how-can-i-perform-search-replace-in-a-text-file-based-on-conditions).

Comment: Hindsight is 20/20... kinda... JabRef needs the `Year`-field to (auto-)generate the key.

Comment: @henry Ah, well ... that's those bibliography programmes for you ...